# Отправка сообщения в беседу VK API через Python

Tags: python, вконтакте, api

Требуется отправить сообщение в беседу. В методах покопался и создал вот это:

```
api.messages.getChat(chat_id='18', message=text)
```

Но сообщения не отправляются. Остальной код работает, так как перед отправкой в беседу идет отправка на стену и там проблем нет, ошибок тоже не выдает. Использую модуль vk. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сам нашел косяк, не тот метод выбрал, надо было api.messages.send(chat_id='18', message=text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chat_id должен быть int (положительное число, максимальное значение 100000000)

Пробуй вот так:

```
api.messages.send(chat_id=18, message=text, random_id=r_id)
```

random_id должен быть равен случайному числу которое не равно предыдущему r_id

Подробнее тут https://vk.com/dev/messages.send